# Android - how to disable second click on the ListView item

Tags: android, listview, click

I have created a simple Android quiz app. When I click on the ListView item the app is working fine. But if I double click on the same item the app crashes. How can I disable the item click after the first click? Thank you.

Comment: We need to see some code to see how you implemented this.

Comment: Yes, please post the relevant code and logcat errors.

Comment: You should not disable the second click, you should fix the reason why the app crashes on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the vague information given it sounds like you are consuming something on the first click and the next time you click that your getting a null value. However, that is a pure guess. Please add code and errors as per everyones comments.